# facebook friends list getting

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get a list of friends with php. I got the necessary permissions, but I can not get a list of friends.

'scope' => 'email, user_friends'

$user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

result:

( [data] => Array ( ) [summary] => Array ( [total_count] => 46 ) )

Comment: That is how the API works. If you read the documentation that is what the documentation say it does

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids clearly states that the Graph API starting with v2.0 only returns the friends which also use the same app.

In your case apparantly nobody of your friends actually uses that app, that's why the result array is empty.

Please use the StackOverflow search the next time before you post a question which was posted here at least 100 times. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, buddy:

```
<?php
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="pic">';
            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>'; 
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```