# Facebook Graph API giving only one response

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the list of my friends name and id using Facebook Android SDK.
When I run my code it shows only one result where as I have 100+ friends on facebook.
Here is my code -

```
new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),"/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        Log.d("Friendslist","Friends : " + response.toString());

                        try{
                        GraphObject gObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        JSONObject jObject = gObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                        Log.d("data",jObject.toString(0));
                        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");

                        for(int i=0; i< jArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject friend = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            friend.getString("id");
                            friend.getString("name");

                        }
                      }
                        catch(JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
```

And my logcat id as follows -

```
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): {
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): "summary": {
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): "total_count": 150
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): },
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): "data": [
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): {
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): "id": "xxxxxxxxx28xxxx",
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): "name": "xxx xxxxxxxx"
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): }
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): ],
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): "paging": {
08-21 06:05:11.346: D/data(1368): "next": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.0\/xxxxxxxx63xxxxxxxxx4\/friends?format=json&access_token={access_token}&limit=5000&offset=5400&__after_id=enc_AewD-Dv80nTxxxxxxxxdOH3DYSP_ElDBc-03aHvRhG0GrHc5DN94S9gwQK7hMpWXF8FFwTZRerWJ3qQ82EgcF"
```

I have even used for loop to get entire list.But, don't know where it fails ?

Comment: This question was at least asked 100 times here. How about reading the appropriate docs first, or search SO before posting a new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402119/facebook-friends-list-getting/25403963#25403963

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not return all the results in a single query.

In the JSON you have a field named "next" with a url. If you call that url will give you the next 25 listings.

Comment: That's not the reason why it fails...

Comment: @Tobi At no time the code is failing. One can not collect all the data in a single query.

Comment: That's not the reason why it doesn't work... He only gets **1** record returned, pagination will kick in at 25. Ever heard of app-scoped user_ids, and that `/me/friends` only return the friends which also use the same app? This was introduced on April 30th 2014 with Graph APi v2.0!